# Is it safe to discharge a water softener into a saltwater swimming pool?

Tags: water-softener

I want to use my water softener's recharge water to fill my pool instead of having it going to the drain. My pool is also a salt water pool.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Water softeners have a discharge to drain that is used during regeneration. He wants to redirect that discharged water from the regeneration process into his swimming pool. Here is a related question, which asks how much waste water is used by water softeners: http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/12130/how-much-water-do-water-softeners-waste

Comment: Placing on hold since the only question asked was added by isherwood. It's not clear that's the same question the OP has.

Comment: Fair enough. @TimB, there's no question in your comment, either. :)

Comment: I think we are being unduly picky. "Description of obviously inventive, hypothetical scenario" implies "Should I do this?"  And it's an excellent question - think people in drought areas where greywater reuse is actively discussed in the pamplets included in our water bills.  Using the recharge water means *not* using fresh water.  Open it up for answers, you never know what you might get.

Answer (score 2):

It will depend what's in your water, among other things - the last place I used a softener, the clear water iron made the softener discharge a very rusty orange. Not exactly appealing for a pool.

If you add salt to a salt-water pool that is presumably losing water primarily via evaporation, it will become hyper-saline over time. I'm not sure how much this would be regarded as a problem in a salt-water pool - perhaps you want it to be like the dead sea - very buoyant.

Even if you don't have iron turning the discharge water rusty, the calcium removed by the softener will accumulate in the pool, and may cause some water quality problems there.

On the whole it seems more likely than not to be a bad idea, but if you are determined to go ahead with it, I'd suggest that you start by catching a bucket of the discharge water and let it sit for a few days, to see if that offers you any insight on what you get with your particular water.

Comment: I wondered about the iron, too. It seems like a chemical analysis is the only way to a proper answer.

Comment: It definitely will add too much salt to the pool.  A saltwater pool needs ~2800-3200ppm sodium chloride.   For those that don't know, electrolysis strips chlorine atoms off to sanitize the water, the return water then passes a sacrificial anode and is recycled back to sodium chloride.  A saltwater pool actually doesn't have much salt, anymore tho and it will taste like saltwater, and effect ph/alkalinity/calcium balance.   Don't discharge your water softener waste into the pool, it's a bad idea.